# Getting current time millisecond is always same in Android onTouchListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am developing an Android App. In my app, I need to get current time millisecond in onTouchListener. What I am doing is when I touch on the view, I memorize that time in millisecond, then when touch exit, I calculate the time difference between first touch and leave.

My code is below:

```
//about container is a linear layout
aboutContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                long timeWhenDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    timeWhenDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }

                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(timeWhenDown) + " - " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

As you can see in the code above, I memorize the time when user touch on layout, then toast the value of current time milliseconds and the time when user touched in. Touch exits after a few seconds. But when exit, it is toasting same value as in the below screenshot.

[image]

Why are these two values same? Actually it should be different since touch down and touch up time are not same. What is wrong with my code? How can I correctly memorize the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the variable `timeWhenDown` as a global variable out side the ontouch function, because this way every touch event `timeWhenDown` is rested to the new value

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    View aboutContainer;
    long timeWhenDown;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        aboutContainer = (View)findViewById(R.id.aboutContainer);

        aboutContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    timeWhenDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }

               else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(timeWhenDown) + " - " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I tested the code and its working fine.

Comment: I did. I declared it as the property of Activity class. But not working. Just the same.

Comment: Have you replaced `long timeWhenDown = System.currentTimeMillis();` with `timeWhenDown = System.currentTimeMillis();`? This seems to be the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer with the right code , you were also returning false which stops the dispatcher from checking another touch events it shoudl return true

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a global arraylist and add millisecond at action down and up and compare those two values.